# MySQL 8.0 Order by condition

Tags: mysql, laravel, sql-order-by

I want to take data from products table. I have to sort by price, but in such a way that first of all it shows those whose price is between the given maximum and minimum.

Example of table:

| Title | price |
| --- | --- |
| Prod 1 | 10 |
| Prod 2 | 8 |
| Prod 3 | 15 |
| Prod 4 | 11 |
| Prod 5 | 12 |
| Prod 6 | 20 |
| Prod 7 | 24 |

If min = 10 and max = 15

The result should be this sequence: **Prod 1, Prod 4, Prod 5, Prod 3, Prod 2, Prod 6, Prod 7**

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why you voted down? I wrote a normal question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort by the boolean expression `price BETWEEN 10 AND 15 DESC` first and then by `price`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY price BETWEEN 10 AND 15 DESC, price;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0de82c06a4b68b00458aa0b9f2168164).

Answer (score 2):

You can use A CASE HWEN  to determine the two groups.

1 for between the price

> ```
> SELECT * FROM product
> ORDER By CASE WHEN `price` BETWEEN 10 AND 15 Then 1 
> ELSE 2 END ASC, `price` ASC
> ```
>
> ```
> Title  | price
> :----- | ----:
> Prod 1 |    10
> Prod 4 |    11
> Prod 5 |    12
> Prod 3 |    15
> Prod 2 |     8
> Prod 6 |    20
> Prod 7 |    24
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=01170a899f08d7cbe961b8a5e5920d01)*

Answer (score 0):

You can also just simply group 2 selects into one with **UNION**.

```
select * from test where value >= 10 and value <= 15
union
select * from test where value < 10 or value > 15
```

[Select Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2c461b16d937089ae9564b03910ac036)